# Executing bash script from puppet fails

Tags: bash, puppet

I have been trying to copy and execute a shell script residing in puppet master machine to my puppet agent

This is my code

```
[root@ip-****** manifests]# cat site.pp
class mymodule::myklass{
  file {'my_bash_script':
      ensure => 'file',
      source => '/etc/puppet/modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh',
      path   => '/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh',
      owner  => 'root',
      mode   => '755',
      notify => Exec['run_my_script'],
  }
  exec { 'run_my_script':
    command => '/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh',
  }
}
include mymodule::myklass
```

my script:

```
[root@ip-********* mymodule]# cat my_bash_script.sh
#!/bin/sh
mv /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/bnode
ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
mv /usr/bin/npm /usr/bin/bnpm
ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[root@ip-*********** /]# puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for ip*****************8
Info: Applying configuration version '1472235841'
Error: /Stage[main]/Mymodule::Myklass/File[my_bash_script]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mymodule::Myklass/Exec[run_my_script]: Dependency File[my_bash_script] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mymodule::Myklass/Exec[run_my_script]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.08 seconds
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the puppet module URI to source your `file` resources if they are located in your `module/files` directories:

```
file {'my_bash_script':
  ensure => 'file',
  source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh',
  path   => '/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh',
  owner  => 'root',
  mode   => '755',
  notify => Exec['run_my_script'],
}
```

Note the documentation here: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/file.html#file-attribute-source

If it still fails with that error, then that means the file is missing from your `$modulepath/mymodule/files/my_bash_script.sh` so you need to place it there.

Furthermore, your bash script could be converted to intrinsic Puppet DSL, and it is odd that you are including a class inside of itself at the end.

Comment: Error: /Stage[main]/Mymodule::Myklass/File[my_bash_script]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh

Comment: thanks. removing the line 'include mymodule::myklass' resolved the error. but the commands i mentioned in the bash script is not executed in the agent. is there anything i am missing ? please let me know

Comment: @Ishwarya Use this https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-logoutput in your `exec` resource to help debug by seeing what the `exec` resource output is actually doing.

Comment: ok thanks. just fyi  i have been trying to copy and execute a shell script 
residing in puppet master machine  to my  puppet agent.

Comment: @ Matt, there is no log of shell script execution coming on puppet client when I tried using accepted answer. My shell script has only one line "echo hi hello", shouldn't "hi hello" get printed in puppet agent log?