# class not found exception -puppet

Tags: puppet

I am trying to copy and execute  the bash script from my puppet master to my puppet agent.

I have create a folder mymodule in /etc/puppet/modules/

```
[root@ip********* mymodule]# ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 30 Aug 26 15:58 files
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 20 Aug 26 16:57 manifests

[root@ip-*********** manifests]# ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 372 Aug 26 16:57 init.pp

[root@ip-************* files]# ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 151 Aug 26 15:13 my_bash_script.sh



 [root@ip-********** files]# cat my_bash_script.sh
        #!/bin/sh
        mv /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/bnode
        ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
        mv /usr/bin/npm /usr/bin/bnpm
        ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm


 [root@ip-********* manifests]# cat init.pp
 class mymodule::mymodule{

 file {'/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh':
      source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/files/my_bash_scrip.sh',
          mode => '755',
           }

    exec {'/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh':
        refreshonly => 'true',
        require => File["/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh"],
        subscribe => File["/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh"],
      }
    }
```

and in my /etc/puppet/manifest/site.pp  i am calling the class created in module.

```
[root@ip-*********** manifests]# cat site.pp
import 'mymodule'

node 'node1' {
    include "mymodule"
}
```

when i run from agent 'puppet agent -t'

i am getting the below error:

```
[root@ip-************8 /]# puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class mymodule for ip-**********8 on node ip-**********8
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Comment: Unless you couldn't reproduce the problem without bash involved (ie. with puppet downloading and running a Python script, for instance), the tag is probably inappropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init manifest (`init.pp`) of your class is expected to be defined as just the class name, like this:

```
class mymodule {
```

and not this:

```
class mymodule::mymodule {
```

so your inclusion of:

```
include "mymodule"
```

matches the class name.

Also, your file resource has a syntax error and a typo. It should look like:

```
file {'/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh':
  source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh',
  mode   => '755',
}
```

Check my answer to your previous question here: [Executing bash script from puppet fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172759/executing-bash-script-from-puppet-fails?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more information about the `source` attribute and the Puppet URI.

Comment: Error: /Stage[main]/Mymodule/File[/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/mymodule/files/my_bash_script.sh
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mymodule/Exec[/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh]: Dependency File[/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mymodule/Exec[/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.05 seconds

Comment: thanks matt. now i am getting this error. is there anything wrong with my script?

Comment: source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh',  its strange though even after changing i am getting the same error this time.

Comment: You also have a typo in your `file` resource. Let me update the answer.

Comment: thanks, but i already noticed  and corrected it.. not able to figure it why i am getting this error